# how to get complete text which is in a docx file table cell into a single string

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I am trying to get the docx file table data in java code using [docx4j api](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j).
Here i am trying to get the each cell data at a time .how to get that data..here i am placing my code which have recursive method calls.

```
static void walkList1(List children) {
    i=children.size();
    int i=1;
    for (Object o : children) {
        if (o instanceof javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) {
            if (((JAXBElement) o).getDeclaredType().getName()
                    .equals("org.docx4j.wml.Text")) {
                org.docx4j.wml.Text t = (org.docx4j.wml.Text) ((JAXBElement) o)
                .getValue();
                System.out.println(" 1 1    " + t.getValue());
            }
        }
        else if (o instanceof org.docx4j.wml.R) {
            org.docx4j.wml.R run = (org.docx4j.wml.R) o;
            walkList1(run.getRunContent());
        } else {
            System.out.println(" IGNORED " + o.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part looks suspicious:

```
i=children.size();
int i=1;
```

The first must be a mutable static field (because otherwise your code will not compile) which is usually a bad idea.  The second is local to the method but is never used.

If you are trying to combine all content into a single `String` I suggest you create a `StringBuilder` and pass that to your recursive calls, e.g.:

```
static String walkList(List children) {
    StringBuilder dst = new StringBuilder();
    walkList1(children, dst);
    return dst.toString();
}
static void walkList1(List children, StringBuilder dst) {
    for (Object o : children) {
        if (o instanceof javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) {
            if (((JAXBElement) o).getDeclaredType().getName()
                    .equals("org.docx4j.wml.Text")) {
                org.docx4j.wml.Text t = (org.docx4j.wml.Text) ((JAXBElement) o)
                .getValue();
                dst.append(t);
            }
        }
        else if (o instanceof org.docx4j.wml.R) {
            org.docx4j.wml.R run = (org.docx4j.wml.R) o;
            walkList1(run.getRunContent(), dst);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" IGNORED " + o.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Also `List<T>` and `JAXBElement<T>` are generic types.  Is there any reason to use the raw types?